# IIS7 URL Rewrite with dynamic subdomains

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

My goal is to implement the following scheme using the subdomain and path as attributes:

Use a wildcard DNS entry that routes any subdomain to the root site:
**Example:**

```
*.example.com 
ex: http://xyz.example.com 
to
http://example.com
```

Next I want to rewrite the requests to point to a specific page, passing both the subdomain and the request path as attributes.

**Example:**

```
http://xyz123.example.com/images/header.jpg 
to
http://example.com/get.aspx?id=xyz123&path=/images/header.jpg
```

I've seen several questions on here regarding similar goals, but not quite the same.  I'm new to using rewrite rules, so any help is appreciated.  I will update this as I make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for IIS7, url rewrite functionality is built-in. Rules are set in web.config. For IIS6 you need an ISAPI dll that does the same for you. Use [IIRF](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/iirf20Help/html/939138c5-f121-44ad-bb6d-139637a22328.htm),  it works just fine.